# Why StreamPlot with Manipulate not working?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm new to Mathematica. Trying to learn by solving simple problems from textbooks. I was trying to use StreamPlot with Manipulate. Some case it works and other cases it does not I don't know the reason.
/* this code worked

```
    m = 1;    
    ssvx = m*(x/(x^2 + y^2));    
    ssvy = m*(y/(x^2 + y^2));    
    StreamPlot[  
    {ssvx, ssvy},    
    {x, -10, 10},{y, -10, 10},    
    ImageSize -> Small    
    ]
```

/* This not working

```
Manipulate[StreamPlot[{ssvx, ssvy}, 
   {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, 
   ImageSize -> Small], {m, -1, 1}]
```

/* Even this not worked

```
ssvx[x_, y_, m_] := m*(x/(x^2 + y^2)); 
ssvy[x_, y_, m_] := m*(y/(x^2 + y^2)); 
Manipulate[StreamPlot[{ssvx[x, y, m], 
    ssvy[x, y, m]}, {x, 1, 10}, 
   {y, 1, 10}, ImageSize -> Small], 
  {m, -1, 1}]
```

/* This worked Why?

```
Manipulate[StreamPlot[    
{(m*x)/(x^2 + y^2),(m*y)/(x^2 + y^2)},    
{x, -10, 10},{y, -10, 10},    
ImageSize -> Medium,    
StreamStyle -> {Hue[Abs[m]/100]}],    
{m, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Your second example is working fine on my system. I'm running mathematica 12.0.0 on Windows. Your first example doesnt work as you probably expect because ssvx was assigned 1*(x/(x^2 + y^2)) and then when Manipulate tries to vary m it doesn't change ssvx.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11.3 on Windows. I just wanted to check StreamPlot in the first example. From 2nd onward I implemented Manipulate function on StreamPlot. Is there a difference between 2nd and 3rd examples?

Comment: Your 3rd example also works. The plot is updated, as expected. However, there are no differences in the plot. You may want to consider functions that produce distinct streams depending on the parameter `m`.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand this "You may want to consider functions that produce distinct streams depending on the parameter" will you elaborate it.

Comment: If you multiply `ssvx` and `ssvy` with the same number `m` the stream plot will look the same, isn't it? What differences do you expect to see?